# Why is mvn clean install throwing lombok error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, lombok

I am trying to run `mvn clean install` on one of my projects. I have the newest version of Intellij installed (2022.2), which has Lombok already bundled with the plugin. However, when I run `mvn clean install` in the project I get a build error:

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor to field com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoveredProcs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.031 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-29T04:25:35-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile)
```

Should I look into downgrading IntelliJ?

As requested in the comments, here is the the full pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.visa.gis.shiftleft</groupId>
    <artifactId>service-registry-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>service-registry-server</name>
    <description>This is a clould service to enable the micro services to register themselves and
        discover other services</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Which JDK do you use? Why using such old maven-compiler-plugin? Which is the target JDK version?

Comment: you should *Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor*

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml

Comment: @khmarbaise currently I am using java 11.0.15 2022-04-19 LTS... let me check if anything changes with 1.8

Comment: Also add the full pom file etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by downgrading to java 1.8